# Laravel 4 workbench, can't access Illuminate facades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, composer-php

I'm developing a package in the Laravel Workbench.

While coding the package unit tests, i need to use some of the Illuminate features, for example i need to use the Artisan facade. So, here's my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "illuminate/support": ">=4.0.0"
},
```

Here's my test case setup:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class myTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function call() on a non-object` during the test run. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at helping. I'm just rattling this off my head, but hopefully it gets you in the right direction.

Did you take a look at the facade class? I do not think that is not how they work.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Artisan.php

To be able to call the Artisan facade, you would need to bind it in the IoC container so that it can be resolved (although I'm not sure if your unit test has enough to bootstrap Laravel to that point). What you should probably do instead is  instantiate the actual object you wanted:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ef0864242e6e6f19a78f941b0710c844016ddf6e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Artisan.php

```
$artisan = new Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan($this->app);
```

Then you can probably do something like:

```
$artisan->migrate(); // Trigger the __call() method of the Artisan class
```

At the end of the day though, I think trying to do database migrations in a unit test is *wrong*. That seems to me to be an integration or [insert favorite buzzword here] type test, and at this level database stuff should be mocked.

Comment: I see your point, but here i need to access Artisan and other Laravel components. Once again, the answer is Orchestral TestBench

Answer (score 0):

here is an example article / template  to kick start laravel workbench with Facade Generation
https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel4-package